# instantiate a controller while using dependency injection

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, inversion-of-control

I am just getting started with Dependency Injection in laravel.  I am having an issue though when trying to use my newly created controller inside one of my routes.

here is my code:

Controller:

```
class BuildQueueController extends BaseController {

   protected $queue;

   public function __construct(BuildQueueInterface $queue) {
      $this->queue = $queue;
   }

   public function all() {
      $ids = $this->queue->all();
      return Response::json($ids);
   }

   public function add() {
      $ids = Input::get('ids');
      try {
         foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $this->queue->add($id);
         }
      } catch (Exception $ex) {
         return Response::json(array("result" => "fail", "except" => $ex->getMessage()));
      }
      return Response::json(array("result" => "pass"));
   }

}
```

the controller is working as expected and I am having no issues getting data when using a route to the functions in the controller.

the issue is in the following code:

```
Route::get('/builder', function() {
   $queueCont = new BuildQueueController();
   $queue = $queueCont->all();

   return View::make('builder');
});
```

I am getting the error "Argument 1 passed to BuildQueueController::__construct() must be an instance of myclass, none given"

I know this is because the constructor is looking for an instance of my interface, but hwo to I get around this in order to use my controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to instantiate controllers manually, you should let Laravel do this for you, but you should be able to instantiate it by using the IoC container:

```
$queueCont = App::make('BuildQueueController');
```

Internally it tries to inject dependencies.